# JSDoc3 - How to document sub-members of a class

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm trying to document something similar to the following where `baz1` and `bazzed` are properties contained in the `bar` and `bar` is a member of `Foo`

```
/**
 * @class
 */
function Foo(){
  this.bar = {
     /**
      * The baz function
      */
     baz1: function(){},
     /**
      * The baz1 function
      */
     bazzed: 'bazzed'
  }
}

var foo = new Foo();

//call baz and baz1
foo.bar.baz();
foo.bar.baz1;
```

Right now JSDoc documents `Foo` and `bar`, but it misses `baz1` and `bazzed`.

I realize that I could do something like this

```
/**
 * @class
 */
function Foo(){
  /**
   * @property {function} baz - Does baz
   * @proprety {string} baz1 - Stores baz1
   */
  this.bar = {
     /**
      * The baz function
      */
     baz1: function(){},
     /**
      * The baz1 function
      */
     bazzed: 'bazzed'
  }
}
```

but I prefer not to for three reasons:

1. Some classes have `baz2:function(){}` through `baz10:function(){}`
2. Some `baz`'s have large comment blocks and it doesn't seem to make sense to include in `bar`'s comment block.
3. In some places the code has `foo.bar.baz.buzz()` which only compounds reasons 1 and 2.

I know this is a really long question, but I've spent the past 4 hours searching to come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

What about listing bar as a child class of Foo?

```
/**
 * @class
 */
function Foo(){
    /**
     * @class
     * @type {{baz1: baz1, bazzed: string}}
     */
    this.bar = {
        /**
         * The baz function
         */
        baz1: function(){},
        /**
         * The baz1 function
         */
        bazzed: 'bazzed'
    }
}
```